# ASP AJAX TABS Sys.InvalidOperationException ERROR 

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hello everyone I have a webform which uses ajax tabs inside the content teplte of the tab I put an user control here is an exapmple

```
 <ajaxtoolkit:tabcontainer id="StyledTabContainer"  runat="server" activetabindex="0"
        width="600px" cssclass="MyTabStyle">

                <!-- Overview Tab -->
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel HeaderText="Overview" CssClass="none" runat="server" ID="TabPanel1" OnClientClick="PanelClickHide">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Overview</h3>

                            <p>
                                &nbsp;<over:Overview id="overview"  runat="server" />
                              </p>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                <!-- Pre-test Tab -->
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel HeaderText="Pre-test" runat="server" ID="TabPanel2" OnClientClick="PanelClickHide">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <h3>Pre-test</h3>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                          <pre:PreTest id="pretest" runat="server" />
                        </p>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                <!-- Webcast -->
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel HeaderText="Webcast"  runat="server" ID="TabPanel3" OnClientClick="PanelClick">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <h3>Webcast</h3>
                        <br />
                        <p id="pvisible" style="display:none">
                            <vid:Video id="vid1" runat="server"/>
                        </p>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                <!-- Post-test Tab -->
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel HeaderText="Post-test" runat="server" ID="TabPanel4" OnClientClick="PanelClickHide">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <h3>Post-Test</h3>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                         <post:Post id="post" runat="server" />
                        </p>    
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxtoolkit:tabcontainer>
```

inside the user control I have a submit button.

on a webform where ajax tabs are located i control which tab to open or close here is example

```
if (status.Part1StartDate != null)
                {
                    StyledTabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
                    TabPanel1.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel2.Enabled = true;
                    TabPanel3.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel4.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel5.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel6.Enabled = false;


                }
                if (status.Part1Done == true)
                {
                    StyledTabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = 2;
                    TabPanel1.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel2.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel3.Enabled = true;
                    TabPanel4.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel5.Enabled = false;
                    TabPanel6.Enabled = false;


                }
```

whenever i Click a button inside the user control which is inside the content template I get this error.

```
    Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException:
 Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.
```

Any help please.....

Thank You

Comment: Have you resolved this Issue